# Conditional computation on values of a dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write a dict comprehension where I want to divide all values of the dict by `(1024 * 1024)` for all the keys except for when the key name is `percent`. The way I am writing it is losing the `percent` key entirely.

How do I still keep it using the kind of comprehension used below?

```
import psutils

virtual_memory_stats = {k: (v/(1024*1024)) for (k, v) in psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict().items() if k != "percent"}

print(virtual_memory_stats)
# {'total': 8192.0, 'available': 2309.91796875, 'used': 4234.609375, 'free': 86.94140625, 'active': 2223.32421875, 'inactive': 2208.53125, 'wired': 2011.28515625}

print(dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict()))
# {'total': 8589934592, 'available': 2409418752, 'percent': 72.0, 'used': 4299833344, 'free': 207478784, 'active': 2202361856, 'inactive': 2184736768, 'wired': 2097471488}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite to this:

```
virtual_memory_stats = {k: (v/(1024*1024)) if k != "percent" else v for (k, v) in psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict().items() }
print(virtual_memory_stats)
```